# How to deploy a Kivy app to Google App Store?

Tags: android, python-3.x, build, kivy, buildozer

Deploying a Kivy app to Google Play Store is a true pain. I spent over a week now trying to deploying the app to the Play Store, whereas I spent only 5 days developing it.

After managing to overcome all problems during the build process with [buildozer](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), I'm facing now another problem when I want to deploy my app to google store. This is the warning I'm getting:

Unoptimised APK
Warning:

```
This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimising your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower installation success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimise for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.
```

I know It's just a warning, I can ignore it right? I thought so too, but google store is not allowing me to deploy my app. So I must somehow solve this issue so that I can finally deploy my app in peace.

Here are the steps I'm making to build my app:

- I followed all these [steps](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Creating-a-Release-APK) (signed the app with key etc...)
- I even tried using jarsigner as an extra step since the steps above didn't work
- I also tried using `zipalign` to "optimize" my app

But none of that worked. Still google store is saying I need to make a bundle android app. But I'm using kivy/python so I can't use android studio to make a bundle and I can't find in buildozer docs how I can do this or if it is supported.

My app size is 28 MB, I even tried to remove some necessary stuff just to see whether it will work. So I reduced the size to 14 MB but that didn't work either. It's really frustrating. Building apps is fun while coding but the deployment process is real headache.

Here is a [link to my app](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator-app) in case you want to play with the code or see the buildozer.spec file. I lost hope of uploading it to Play Store, hence I open sourced it.

### Edit

here is how the google play console looks in my case:

This is the first tab, where I upload the app:

[image: This is the first tab, where I upload the app]

This is the second tab, where I should review and then release (notice here that I can't press the roll out to production button):

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not the actual size, but the format you are deploying. You are uploading APK file and you need to upload AAB file. See [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle) I am not familiar with Kivy apps, so I don't know how to build aab in your case.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Excatly, I was looking on how to bundle my kivy app all the time, but I can't find a way to do it. I can't use android studio since my app is not written in java

Comment: This is not what you asked. Signing and optimizing apk will not magically produce different file format. You should ask how to build app bundle with your toolset and half of your question is revolving about reducing apk format size which is not relevant.

Comment: Of course it's relevant. I posted a question in reddit and all people there asked about my app size. Therefore I wrote it here directly so that no one wonder what is my app size! Also the title of my question is how to deploy my kivy app to google app store! Furthermore, I declared all steps I made and posted links to my project. I feel like some people on stackoverflow are just trying to prove that others are wrong! It's really weird! plus I'm getting my question downvoted although I describe it very good and explained everything. Anyway thanks I ll delete the question

Comment: Feel free to ignore people that are trying to help you. Your actual file size is not relevant to the problem. you can upload 1 MB APK file and get the same warning. You need AAB file. Half of your question is not relevant to your problem. I commented because it was not clear to me that you fully understand problem you are facing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't deploy because you've failed to fill in something on another page of the app config. As you guess, the obvious message is just a warning, not something that blocks the app being deployed. I've seen this same question several times recently, and every time it was resolved by something elsewhere in the config.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think you're wrong about needing to upload an AAB file, can you link any documentation showing that this is essential?

Comment: @inclement Thanks for the hint. However, I actually can't deploy my app without overcoming the warning. Google store will not allow me to click the deploy button until I deal with the warning. Can you take a look at my config? I assume you mean buildozer config right? I posted the link to the repo already

Comment: No, I mean the app configuration in the play console. I think the warning message is unrelated to your inability to click the deploy button.

Comment: @inclement I edit the question by posting two screenshots of the google play console. I tried to fill out all config that exists there, but I keep getting the warning and can't press the release button. The only thing that I didn't add are screenshots and photos of my app, but I assume that can't be the reason why I can't release the app right?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. Note that next to "Store Listing" there is a greyed-out ✓, compared to the green ones on other pages. Look at the Store Listing page and do whatever is necessary to make it green.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you do need some minimum number of images uploaded.

Comment: @inclement Exactly the store listing is greyed out because it requires some screenshots of the app. I never though that they are required to make a release. Alright then I will try to do it and edit the question whether if it worked or not. Thank you for these hints

Comment: @inclement Oh man unbelievable, you are right! I needed to fill all those config in order to make a release. It had nothing to do with my apk. If you want to right an answer about this, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Great, I've added an answer that I'll be glad to be able to point people at - thanks especially for the screenshot which is a good reference to show what needs doing. I'm sure we'll see more people with the same issue arising from google's unclear messaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, the message you're seeing about using AAB is just a warning, it doesn't prevent you from releasing the app. You're far from the first person to be confused by it though, the google interface is quite unclear.

[image: ui screenshot]

The actual problem is that you need to make sure all the essential information is filled in on every page of the app store configuration. In your screenshot above, pages that have been completed are marked by a green circle with a check mark. In contrast, the "Store Listing" page only has a greyed-out check mark, indicating that you need to add something there before you can release the APK.

As discussed in comments, it turned out that the missing thing was screenshots of the app, and after adding them it could be released successfully despite the warning message.